# SELECT data quickly without other rows interfering with %(mod) operator

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, subquery

I have a database logging historical results to file.

The results are logged to a table created by

```
CREATE TABLE Data (TimeID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES StartTimes, 
                   TimeOffset REAL,
                   SensorID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Sensors,
                   Value REAL);
```

I have an index over (TimeID, TimeOffset) and can create more as needed - my INSERT performance is fine for the time being and hopefully should remain so.

I read data out to place the data on a graph using

```
SELECT SensorID, TimeOffset, Value from Data 
WHERE ((TimeID = %d AND TimeOffset BETWEEN %f AND %f) AND 
(%s));
```

where %s is replaced by strings to the effect of "(SensorID=1 and ROWID%5=0) or (SensorID=2 and ROWID%5000=0)", %d is a constant value in a prepared statement, and the %f are bound to correspond with the limits of the graph.

My problem here becomes that if I had two sensors logging an an equal rate, a single point each, and if my value to use taking the modulus became e.g. 2, then I get all of the data from one sensor, and nothing from the other (I think?).

I tried using

```
SELECT COUNT(lesser.TimeOffset) as NewID, D.TimeOffset from Data as D
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data as lesser on D.rowid > lesser.rowid and D.TimeID=%d and D.SensorID=1
GROUP BY D.TimeOffset;
```

but on the command line (using an example value for TimeID) the command line processes for a very long time (possibly I've completely miswritten the statement).

How can I SELECT a subset of the Data using those kind of constraints (TimeID=?, TimeOffset BETWEEN ? AND ?) and quickly grab by SensorID a collection that isn't affected by the writing of other measurements?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use MIN(x) and MAX(x) to find the highest and lowest values in a given range of TimeOffset, but it seems I have no way of doing this quickly (that I can work out - I'm new to SQL(ite) though). Consequently, I've just opted for the % operator.

**Edit - Example Table Contents:**

```
SELECT * from Data LIMIT 10;

TimeID|TimeOffset|SensorID|Value
1|0.0|1|0.464069664478302
1|0.0|2|0.0
1|0.00100000004749745|2|0.00251327152363956
1|0.0020000000949949|2|0.00502652721479535
1|0.00300000002607703|2|0.00753975100815296
1|0.00400000018998981|2|0.010052926838398
1|0.00499999988824129|2|0.0125660402700305
1|0.00600000005215406|2|0.0150790736079216
1|0.00700000021606684|2|0.0175920110195875
1|0.00800000037997961|2|0.0201048385351896
```

With my made up data (being used to test implementation) I have a random number between 0 and 1 as Sensor #1 at 1Hz, and a sine wave as #2 at 1kHz. (These aren't written one point at a time, but I still feel I could shoot myself in the foot using rowid%x to decimate)

TimeOffset measures the time since the start of data acquisition, whilst the TimeID references a StartTime in the StartTimes table (YmDHMS etc).

**Justification**

Since there are often far fewer pixels on a screen than the number of points available to place in the relevant timespan, choosing only some points is sensible to cut down the amount of data I'm trying to read from the database.

Using the % operator gives me evenly spaced points, but can easily lose the shape of the data in some circumstances.

Use of min/max decimation can prevent this, but to use it, you need to find minimum and maximum values in each timespan corresponding to e.g. a pixel's width. If I don't do this inside the query, then I have to read all of the data from the database between the bounds of the graph, of which I might only plot some small (sub 1%) fraction.

Comment: I can also consider using a separate table for each sensor, but I'm not certain that would be a faster idea. It would remove the other sensors' results from the problem though, which might be worthwhile.

Comment: It may be helpful if you add examples of: your table contents, the currently retrieved result with its query, and the desired result.

Comment: It seems like the `WITH` clause can improve my queries quite significantly. I can use them to take only a small fraction of the full `Data` table, and then conduct the `JOIN` on that subset, without the additional constraints to the `ON` clause (which seem to have been a large part of the problem). Do subqueries not allow indices to be used? Or is my posted query just never getting past the `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compute the index of an entry inside the data acquisition series with a subquery, but that would be slow.

The most efficient way of filtering out the unwanted rows is probably to do this in your program, i.e., query all of them, in the correct order, and just step over all of them except each *n*-th.
(This requires sorting, but `ORDER BY TimeID, TimeOffset` does not cost anything because the results are already sorted due to the index.)

You could improve your query further by using a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx), but for this table, a [clustered index](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) (with the PK over the first three columns) would be even better.
Also, make the order of colunms `TimeID, SensorID, TimeOffset`, because [only the right-most used column in an index can optimize inequalities](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#where_clause).

Comment: I know that when I use a `SELECT` statement, I should use the constraints in the order `TimeID, SensorID, TimeOffset`, but I just want to check - is that what you meant here, or does the order in which the columns are stored by `CREATE TABLE` also bear some effect on performance? I'll take a look at using a `WITHOUT ROWID` table and see how I do - this would be possible so long as I process in the application rather than the db as you say (since there I can use array indices)

Comment: The order in the SELECT statement does not matter, only the order in the index. (In a clustered index, that's the table order.)

Comment: Oops. Better check I didn't mess this up then. Will reread on clustered indices.